# How to track & filter several languages of one TLD without subdirectories like "/en" in one google analytics property?

Tags: google-analytics

Is this impossible? We would like to track one domain with several languages in one Google Analytics property in order to have all the traffic of the different languages in one view (profile). But especially we would like to filter each language in one view (profile). Is that possible and how can it be achieved? The top level domain doesn't have subdirectories for the different languages so we can't filter by country code in the URL. We are using the new analytics universal code. Does anyone have an idea? Thanks for your help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume there is a language switcher somewhere in your page. You could get the selected language by examining the DOM element that holds the language settings.

HTML for a language switcher might look like this:

```
<div id="language">
<span class="active">DE</span>
<span>EN</span>
<div>
```

Assuming you use jQuery (because that makes explaining simpler for me, not because it is necessary) you could select the language:

```
lang = jQuery('#language .active').text();
```

Then you could do either a virtual pageview to recored the language as a part of the url path

```
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview' , lang + "/" + window.location.pathname]);
```

and set up a request url filter or track the language setting as an event (custom var would not quite work, since you cannot filter by custom var).

Edit: With analytics.js you would of course use ga send:

```
ga('send', 'pageview',   lang + "/" + window.location.pathname);
```

but the principle is the same.

Comment: We implemented your idea not with jQuery but with php and it works fine!!